# $cordovaInAppBrowser events are not being fired

Tags: angularjs, cordova, typescript, dropbox-api, inappbrowser

I searched in the form and checked out related topics but nothing really worked for me. 
I need to close the InAppBrowser when the url has the token and take the token from the url.
So far i cant detect when the url changes in inAppBrowser. Any ideas what i do wrong ?

*console.log("event fired") never works :/

Controller:

```
openDropboxDialog() {
      let str = this.DropboxService.getDropboxUrl();
      this.$cordovaInAppBrowser.open(str, '_blank', this.DropboxService.getOptions());
      this.$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstart', (e, event) => {
        console.log("event fired")
        if (event.url.indexOf("token") > -1) {
          this.$cordovaInAppBrowser.close();
        }
      });

    }
```

Service :

```
 getDropboxUrl() {
      let dbx = new Dropbox({ clientId: this.CLIENT_ID });
      let str = dbx.getAuthenticationUrl("http://localhost:8100")
      return str;
  }
```

Comment: Did you try to put open-method after the event-listener?

Comment: Yeah i did right now.. No success :/

Comment: Are you sure that your localhost can be reached? Its worth a try to define a loaderror-listener as well.

Comment: remove `this.` before `$rootScope` and `$cordovaInAppBrowser`

Comment: Why should i delete "this" ?! I mean i use dependency injection in typescript, how should i reach thedependency then ?